# How can I add files to a cab-file from VBA, using cabinet.dll API calls?

Tags: winapi, cab

Cabinet.dll provides a collection of functions to compress/extract files and manage CAB files. I'd like to use it with VBA. There are few examples online using these features in VBA.

I want to add individual files to an existing CAB. That might be possible with the fx Compress or FCIAddFile. But I haven't found any VBA examples with FCIAddFile.

I attempted the following declarations. Inline comments describe the errors:

```
Enum CompressionType
          MSZIP = 2
          XPRESS = 3
          XPRESS_HUFF = 4
          LZMS = 5
End Enum


Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompressor& Lib "cabinet" (ByVal CompressAlgorithm&, ByVal pAllocationRoutines&, hCompressor&)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Compress& Lib "cabinet" (ByVal hCompressor&, ByVal pUncompressedData As String, ByVal sizeUncompressedData&, ByVal pCompressedDataBuffer As String, ByVal sizeCompressedBuffer&, bytesOut&)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateDecompressor& Lib "cabinet" (ByVal CompressAlgorithm&, ByVal pAllocationRoutines&, hDecompressor&)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Decompress& Lib "cabinet" (ByVal hCompressor&, ByVal pCompressedData&, ByVal sizeCompressedData&, ByVal pUncompressedDataBuffer&, ByVal sizeOfUncompressedBuffer&, bytesOut&)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseCompressor& Lib "cabinet" (ByVal hCompressor&)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseDecompressor& Lib "cabinet" (ByVal hDecompressor&)

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FCIAddFile& Lib "cabinet" (ByVal hfci&, ByVal pszSourceFile&, ByVal pszFileName&, ByVal fExecute&, ByVal pfnfcignc&, ByVal pfnfcis&, ByVal pfnfcigoi&, ByVal typeCompress&)


Function CompressString$(s$, Optional algorithm& = 5)
          Dim h&, max&, bytesOut&, b$
          CreateCompressor algorithm, 0&, h
          max = LenB(s): b = Space$(max)

          FCIAddFile h, "C:\Data\Network info.txt", "Network info.txt", False, 0&, 0&, 0&, XPRESS     ' <-- TYPE MISMATCH ERROR

          Compress h, StrPtr(s), max, StrPtr(b), max, bytesOut
          If bytesOut Then CompressString = Left$(b, bytesOut \ 2)
          CloseCompressor h     ' <-- EXCEL CRASHES IF THIS LINE IS ALLOWED TO EXECUTE
End Function
```

Borrowed from https://newbedev.com/excel-vba-compression-code-example

---

I don't understand why the constants appear to be different than the [CreateCompressor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/compressapi/nf-compressapi-createcompressor) function.

**CreateCompressor:**

```
MSZIP = 2
XPRESS = 3
XPRESS_HUFF = 4
LZMS = 5
```

**[FCIAddFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fci/nf-fci-fciaddfile):**

```
tcompTYPE_NONE: 0x0000
tcompTYPE_MSZIP: 0x0001
```

Comment: If the goal is to create a ZIP archive, then there's nothing in the Windows API that would allow you to do that.

Comment: @IInspectable Are you referring to something in my question?